# QrCode C/C++ API For Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, qr-code

I have looked after, without luck, a free C/C++ API for Windows that can be used in a project I am about to start. There are libraries for Java and C# but the fact is there is no one for C/C++. I need an API that can be integrated in a vs project and we cannot use libraries that run in servers ( as CGI scripts or whatever ). Does anyone know this type of API?

Comment: I am using this REST api found here for one of my projects with similar restrictions. Seems to work well. https://fungenerators.com/api/qrcode/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to generate QRcodes have a look at [libqrencode](http://megaui.net/fukuchi/works/qrencode/index.en.html) it works with cygwin on windows (not sure about VS).

If you want to decode QRcodes have a look at [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

Comment: Thanks, I want to generate QRCodes. Anyway, I knew libqrebcode, but it would take some effort to make it work with VS ( which we use for GUI ). Do you know how portable this code is, i.e., if it uses UNIX based APIs.

Comment: the buildfile works on cygwin and some of the tests/examples use sql or libpng, don't know if anyone has made a vs build yet

Comment: It looks like it will configure and build just fine with MinGW and MSYS as long as you have SDL and PNG. I have PNG but not SDL so I didn't pursue the build past that point. Other than that, the sources look like a dozen C files, so it may make more sense to just attempt to build them directly in VS. There's no reason why they would need to be too Unix dependent inside, and the project might welcome a patch if they are.